# What wrong with my application? nullpointerExcepttion?

Tags: java, android

everybody
I'm a new to Android.

I'm  got an error in my application.

Here's the picture of error i had capture. [enter link description here](http://upic.me/i/wb/0error.jpg)

Can you please help me to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Here  my code:

```
public class DBAdapter 
{
    public static final String UPDATEDATE = "UpdateDate"; 
    //Declare fields in PersonInfo
    public static final String ROWID = "_id";

    public static final String PT_FirstName = "FirstName";
    public static final String PT_SecondName = "SecondName";
    public static final String PT_Gender = "Gender";
    public static final String PT_PatientId = "PatientId";
    public static final String PT_PeopleId = "PeopleId";
    public static final String PT_TreatmentRight = "TreatmentRight";
    public static final String PT_Birthday = "Birthday";
    public static final String PT_Address = "Address";
    public static final String PT_HomePhone = "HomePhone";
    public static final String PT_CellPhone = "CellPhone";
    public static final String PT_Email = "Email";
    public static final String PT_ContactName = "ContactName";
    public static final String PT_ContactPhone = "ContactPhone";
    public static final String PT_Occupation = "Occupation";
    public static final String PT_BloodType ="BloodType";
    public static final String PT_Prefix = "Prefix";
    public static final String PT_Province = "Province";
    public static final String PT_PatientType = "PatientType";  
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table PatientInfo (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "PatientId text ,PatientType text , Prefix text , Gender text, "
        + "FirstName text, SecondName text, PeopleId text, TreatmentRight text, "
        + "Birthday text, BloodType text, Occupation text, Address text, "
        + "Province text, HomePhone text, CellPhone text, Email text, "
        + "ContactName text, ContactPhone text);"; 
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "clinic.db";
    public static final String tbPatient = "PatientInfo";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);        
    }


    //start database helper class
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            //nothing for now
        }
    }    
    //end database helper class

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLiteException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getPersonList(){
        return db.query(tbPatient, new String[] {
                ROWID,
                PT_PatientId, 
                PT_PatientType, 
                PT_Prefix,
                PT_Gender,
                PT_FirstName,
                PT_SecondName,
                PT_PeopleId,
                PT_TreatmentRight,
                PT_Birthday,
                PT_BloodType,
                PT_Occupation,
                PT_Address,
                PT_Province,
                PT_HomePhone,
                PT_CellPhone,
                PT_Email,
                PT_ContactName,
                PT_ContactPhone}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null,
                null);
    }   

    public long insertPerson(String patientid,String patienttype,String prefix,String gender,String firstname,
            String secondname,String peopleid,String treatmentright,String birthday,
            String bloodtype,String occupation,String address,String province,
            String homephone,String cellphone,String email,String contactname,
            String contactphone) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(PT_PatientId,patientid); 
        initialValues.put(PT_PatientType,patienttype); 
        initialValues.put(PT_Prefix,prefix); 
        initialValues.put(PT_Gender,gender); 
        initialValues.put(PT_FirstName,firstname); 
        initialValues.put(PT_SecondName,secondname); 
        initialValues.put(PT_PeopleId,peopleid); 
        initialValues.put(PT_TreatmentRight,treatmentright); 
        initialValues.put(PT_Birthday,birthday); 
        initialValues.put(PT_BloodType,bloodtype); 
        initialValues.put(PT_Occupation,occupation); 
        initialValues.put(PT_Address,address); 
        initialValues.put(PT_Province,province); 
        initialValues.put(PT_HomePhone,homephone);
        initialValues.put(PT_CellPhone,cellphone);
        initialValues.put(PT_Email,email);
        initialValues.put(PT_ContactName,contactname);
        initialValues.put(PT_ContactPhone,contactphone);
        return db.insert(tbPatient, null, initialValues);
     }

    public boolean updatePerson(long recordid, String patientid,String patienttype,String prefix,String gender,String firstname,
                                String secondname,String peopleid,String treatmentright,String birthday,
                                String bloodtype,String occupation,String address,String province,
                                String homephone,String cellphone,String email,String contactname,
                                String contactphone) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

        args.put(PT_PatientId,patientid); 
        args.put(PT_PatientType,patienttype); 
        args.put(PT_Prefix,prefix); 
        args.put(PT_Gender,gender); 
        args.put(PT_FirstName,firstname); 
        args.put(PT_SecondName,secondname); 
        args.put(PT_PeopleId,peopleid); 
        args.put(PT_TreatmentRight,treatmentright); 
        args.put(PT_Birthday,birthday); 
        args.put(PT_BloodType,bloodtype); 
        args.put(PT_Occupation,occupation); 
        args.put(PT_Address,address); 
        args.put(PT_Province,province); 
        args.put(PT_HomePhone,homephone);
        args.put(PT_CellPhone,cellphone);
        args.put(PT_Email,email);
        args.put(PT_ContactName,contactname);
        args.put(PT_ContactPhone,contactphone);
        return db.update(tbPatient, args, 
              ROWID + "=" + recordid, null) > 0;
    }

    public boolean deletePerson(long recordid) 
    {
        return db.delete(tbPatient, ROWID + 
                "=" + recordid, null) > 0;
    }



    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

                db.query(tbPatient, new String[] {
                        ROWID,
                        PT_PatientId, 
                        PT_PatientType, 
                        PT_Prefix,
                        PT_Gender,
                        PT_FirstName,
                        PT_SecondName,
                        PT_PeopleId,
                        PT_TreatmentRight,
                        PT_Birthday,
                        PT_BloodType,
                        PT_Occupation,
                        PT_Address,
                        PT_Province,
                        PT_HomePhone,
                        PT_CellPhone,
                        PT_Email,
                        PT_ContactName,
                        PT_ContactPhone}, ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }


}






//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


public class PatientInfo extends Activity{
    private TextView firstNameEdt;
    private TextView patientIdEdt;
    private TextView lastNameEdt;
    private TextView peopleIdEdt;
    private TextView birthdayEdt;
    private TextView addressEdt;
    private TextView homePhoneEdt;
    private TextView cellPhoneEdt;
    private TextView emailEdt;
    private TextView contactNameEdt;
    private TextView contactPhoneEdt;
    private TextView GenderEdt;
    private TextView OccupationEdt;
    private TextView BloodTypeEdt;
    private TextView PrefixEdt;
    private TextView ProvinceEdt;
    private TextView TreatmentRightEdt;
    private TextView PatientTypeEdt ;
    private DBAdapter dbPatient;
    private Button exitBtn;
    private Button editBtn;

    private Button addAppointmentBtn;
    private Long rowId;
    String S_PatientType=" ";
    String S_Gender=" ";
    String S_Occupation=" ";
    String S_BloodType=" ";
    String S_Prefix=" ";
    String S_Province=" ";
    String S_TreatmentRight=" ";
    String S_Birthday=" ";
    String S_PatientId=" ";
    String S_FirstName=" ";
    String S_SecondName=" ";
    String S_PeopleId=" ";
    String S_Address=" ";
    String S_HomePhone=" ";
    String S_CellPhone=" ";
    String S_Email=" ";
    String S_ContactName =" ";
    String S_ContactPhone =" ";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbPatient = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbPatient.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.patientinfo);
        setBinding();


        rowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(DBAdapter.ROWID) 
                : null;
if (rowId == null) {
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
rowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(DBAdapter.ROWID) 
        : null;
}

populateFields();



       // dataPreparation();
        setEvent();


}



    private void populateFields() {
        if (rowId != null) {
            Cursor note = dbPatient.fetchNote(rowId);
            startManagingCursor(note);
            firstNameEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_FirstName)));
            lastNameEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_SecondName)));
            GenderEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_Gender)));
            patientIdEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_PatientId)));
            peopleIdEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_PeopleId)));
            TreatmentRightEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_TreatmentRight)));
            birthdayEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_Birthday)));

            addressEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_Address)));

            homePhoneEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_HomePhone)));

            cellPhoneEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_CellPhone)));

            emailEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_Email)));

            contactNameEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_ContactName)));

            contactPhoneEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_ContactPhone)));

            OccupationEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_Occupation)));

            BloodTypeEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_BloodType)));

            PrefixEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_Prefix)));

            ProvinceEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_Province )));

            PatientTypeEdt.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.PT_PatientType)));
        }
    }

    private void setBinding(){
         editBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
         exitBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
         dbPatient =  new DBAdapter(this);
         addAppointmentBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addAppointment);
         PatientTypeEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.patient_Type);
         GenderEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
         OccupationEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.occupation);
         BloodTypeEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blood_Type);
         PrefixEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prefix);
         ProvinceEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.province);
         TreatmentRightEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.treatment_Right);
         birthdayEdt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.birthday);
         patientIdEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.patient_id);
         firstNameEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_Name);
         lastNameEdt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_Name);
         peopleIdEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id2);
         addressEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
         homePhoneEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_Phone);
         cellPhoneEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cell_Phone);
         emailEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
         contactNameEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_Name);
         contactPhoneEdt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_Phone);

     } 


     private void setEvent() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         addAppointmentBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent showLinearLayout = new Intent(PatientInfo.this,AddAppointment.class);
                    startActivity(showLinearLayout);
                }
            });





         exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent showLinearLayout = new Intent(PatientInfo.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(showLinearLayout);
                }
            });

         editBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent showLinearLayout = new Intent(PatientInfo.this,AddPatient.class);
                    startActivity(showLinearLayout);
                }
            });

}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class SearchPatient extends ListActivity{
    private DBAdapter dbPatient;
    private EditText appointmentDateEdt;
    private Spinner typeSelectSpn;
    private Button exitBtn;
    private Button searchBtn;
    private Cursor personListCursor;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchpatient);
        setBinding();
        dataPreparation();
        listData();
        setEvent();

}
     private void setBinding(){
         typeSelectSpn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_Type);
         exitBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
         searchBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
         dbPatient =  new DBAdapter(this);
     } 


     private void setEvent() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent showLinearLayout = new Intent(SearchPatient.this,PatientInfo.class);
                    startActivity(showLinearLayout);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putLong("ROWID", 0);
                    showLinearLayout.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(showLinearLayout);
                }

            });

        }


     private void listData(){
         dbPatient.open();
            personListCursor = dbPatient.getPersonList();
            startManagingCursor(personListCursor);
            String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.PT_PatientId,DBAdapter.PT_FirstName, DBAdapter.PT_SecondName,DBAdapter.PT_PatientType };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.patient_id2, R.id.firstname2, R.id.lastname2, R.id.patient_type2};

            // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
            SimpleCursorAdapter personList =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.datarow, personListCursor, from, to){

            };
            setListAdapter(personList);
            //dbPatient.close();
        }


     @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, PatientInfo.class);
            i.putExtra(DBAdapter.ROWID, id);
            startActivity(i);
        }







     private void dataPreparation()

        {
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.search, 
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);     
                        Adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        typeSelectSpn.setAdapter(Adapter1);
        }


}
```

Comment: OMG - too much code tp read, and badly formatted.  If you're getting an NPE, the stack trace will have the line number at which the exception was thrown.  Find it, open your code in an IDE that shows line numbers, go to that line, and stare at it until you figure out which object on that line might be null.

Comment: -1 because you didn't try to debug it yourself. This site is not for debugging your entire code but for helping with a problem, for that you have to identify the problem first or at least pinpoint it.

Answer (score 0):

`db` may be null in `fetchNote()` .. perhaps you didn't open the database with a call to `open()`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace it looks like `db` is null in `fetchNote()` because you haven't called `open()` yet. Nothing else in that methods appears it would cause a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put an explicit nullcheck in your fetchnote method:

```
public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {
     if(db==null){
        return null;
     }
        Cursor mCursor =

                db.query(tbPatient, new String[] {
                        ROWID,
                        PT_PatientId, 
                        PT_PatientType, 
                        PT_Prefix,
                        PT_Gender,
                        PT_FirstName,
                        PT_SecondName,
                        PT_PeopleId,
                        PT_TreatmentRight,
                        PT_Birthday,
                        PT_BloodType,
                        PT_Occupation,
                        PT_Address,
                        PT_Province,
                        PT_HomePhone,
                        PT_CellPhone,
                        PT_Email,
                        PT_ContactName,
                        PT_ContactPhone}, ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }
```

But your open method seems to initialize "db". Perhaps it is not called? Or perhaps DBHelper.getWritableDatabase() returns null?

I would also recommend the following:

```
 //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLiteException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if(db==null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Database could not be opened");
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

NullPointer coming in **fetchNote** method in **DBAdapter** class :
Cursor is returning null there..

check the exact line of code: **DBAdapter line no. 192**